# Property name without System.Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

It is possible to get property name from code in dotnet without use Reflection?

```
int PropWithNiceName
{
get {Console.Writeline( ??? )}
}
```

Comment: Which property you want?

Comment: Yes, absolutely: `Console.Writeline("PropWithNiceName")` will work :)

Comment: As the above says - you will inevitably know the name of the property in the get method so why do you have to have a form of methodology to go and fetch it - just hardcode it.

Comment: I would like to get PropWithNiceName

Comment: @Jacek - `dasblinkenlight` answers your question then. You know the name in property itself. Isn't it?

Comment: dasblinkenlight give good answer (I rate his comment), but it doesn't work with properties with other names :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes; you can use the new `[CallerMemberName]` attribute:

```
static string MemberName([CallerMemberName] string name = null) {
    return name;
}

int MyProperty {
    set {
        Console.WriteLine(MemberName());
    }
}
```

Comment: The funny thing is, doing it like this will result in the code: Console.WriteLine("MyProperty"); actually being generated after compiling...